# If $|(f^n)'(\hat{x})|>1$, is there a neighborhood of a fixed point such that all points in the interval leaves it under iterations?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I have to prove the following theorem

> **Theorem**. Let $f$ be a function of class $\mathcal{C}^1$ on $S$ and let $\hat{x}$ be a periodic point of $f$ of period $n$,
>
> - If $|(f^n)'(\hat{x})|<1$, then there is a neighborhood of $\hat{x}$ contained in $W^S(\hat{x})$.
> - If $|(f^n)'(\hat{x})|>1$, then there is a neighborhood $V$ of $\hat{x}$ such that all points in the interval $V$ except $\hat{x}$
>   must leave the interval $V$ under iteration of $f$.

I proved first point proving that $|f'(x)|<1-\epsilon \ \ \forall x \in B_\delta(\hat{x})$ and $f^n(x) \rightarrow \hat{x}$ as $n \rightarrow+\infty$

The second point I want to prove that $|f^n(\hat{x})|>1$ implies $\exists V=B_\delta(\hat{x})$ such that $B_\delta(\hat{x})\setminus\hat{x} \ \cap f^n(x) = \emptyset$. I think that proving that, the theorem should be resolved but I don't really know how to do it. Any clue?

Comment: Maybe you can use that $f^n$ is locally invertible at $\hat{x}$ with $|f^{-n}(\hat{x})| < 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

Let $v=|f'(x)|>1$ and let $K\in\mathbb{R}, 1<K<v$. As $f\in\mathcal{C}^1$, $f'$ is continuous so $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0$ s.t. $x\in B_\delta(\hat{x}) \implies |f'(x)|>K$.

Let $x\in B_\delta(\hat{x}), x \neq \hat{x}$ and applying MVT, $\exists c \in B_\delta(\hat{x})$ s.t.
$$|f(x)-f(\hat{x})| = |f(x)-\hat{x}| = |f'(c)||x-\hat{x}| > K|x-\hat{x}|.$$
By induction,
$$|f^n(x)-\hat{x}| > K^n|f^n(x)-\hat{x}|,$$
and as $K>1, K^n\longrightarrow+\infty$ when $n\longrightarrow+\infty$. So
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|f^n(x)-\hat{x}| = +\infty.$$